# Is it safe to manually delete binary logs after disabling it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

After disabling log-bin by `skip-log-bin` option, I cannot use `PURGE` command to remove binary logs.

Refer to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html)

> PURGE BINARY LOGS requires the BINLOG_ADMIN privilege. This statement has no effect if the server was not started with the --log-bin option to enable binary logging.

My question is: If I need reenable log-bin in the future, is it safe to delete remaining binary logs with `rm binlog.*` command now?

Comment: What is the goal of deleting the files?  Save space?  Something else?

Comment: To save space .

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not delete them by hand, it isn't safe.

If you can't use PURGE to remove binary logs, consider using [binlog_expire_logs_seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds) which will remove automatically the binary log files after their expiration period ends.

Comment: Both `--binlog-expire-logs-seconds=1 --skip-log-bin` and `--binlog-expire-logs-seconds=1 --disable-log-bin` didn't delete any binary logs. With only `--binlog-expire-logs-seconds=1` option, mysqld deleted old binary logs but it created a new one too.